# Accidentally resilvered 2 drives

Tags: solaris, zfs, solaris-10

We had 2 failed drives in our ZFS raidz1 pool. One had been resilvered to a spare and another was just out. The pool was in degraded mode.

I replaced both drives and began the resilver on the non-spare drive. Without thinking, I forced a resilver on the one that was currently running on the spare. The pool is now reporting LOTS of data errors.

Is there any way to recover from this or am I totally screwed? I would think that since the spare is still available, we're still only down 1 drive and the data should technically all be there. Also, did I cause this or did I just uncover existing data corruption?

Comment: What **exactly** did you do? You can't force ZFS to "resilver", it does it on it's own.

Comment: Obligatory "RAID is not backup" comment.

Comment: Chris: I did a zpool replace -f app-pool (disk ID) for both disks.

Comment: Yeah, you're screwed. Can I ask why you would have included the `-f` option? It's one of those things they shouldn't have included in the first place, and there's no valid reason to use it ever.

Comment: I did it to the 1st disk because it HAD been part of another pool and it gave me an error. On the 2nd disk it was a mistake.

Comment: Also David, I've been fighting for a proper backup for months. I work at a government installation. Nothing is easy.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why forcing a replacement on two disks that were already offline would cause this problem though. It's not like I removed active disks that were being read from.